# What is the corresponding idiom "camel toe" for men?

Tags: slang, idiom-request

**["Camel toe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_toe)** is the name of the condition when the sexual organ of the women is projecting out from the pants. Then my question is what is the corresponding alsng or idiom for this condition in men, it says when the sexual organ of the men is projecting out from the pants?

Sources:

[Wikipedia -camel toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_toe)

[Oxford dictionary- camel toe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/camel_toe)

[Collins dictionary - camel toe](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/camel-toe)

[image: From Wikipedia]

Comment: "Lunchbox" as describing the physique British sprinter Linford Christie

Comment: I think everyone knows this term: *bulge*. Image search for "men's bulges" and you will get the picture, umm, lots of pictures, actually!

Answer (score 4):

[Moose knuckle](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Moose%20Knuckles) is the one I've heard.  But it's not as common an expression, so I don't know if everyone will understand what you mean.

[Additional supporting evidence](https://www.buzzfeed.com/mjs538/a-worst-moose-knuckles-at-the-olympics?utm_term=.ddEmNx1jW#.asm5PXrJN)

I've also heard "camel toe" used for men, although it's not as common as for women.

Comment: [The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Knuckles) also suggests "knuckle" as a slang term for male genitalia; derived from "moose knuckle".

Answer (score 3):

The male equivalent is known, in Australia, and I think in the British Isles too, as the **budgie (budgy) smuggler**.

> *[Is it ever OK to wear 'budgie smugglers'?](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/fashion-and-style/10744084/Is-it-ever-OK-to-wear-budgie-smugglers.html)*
>
> The Speedo-style swimming trunk is back, courtesy of David Beckham and his new H&M campaign, posturing in tiny slivers of poly-blend, effectively proposing that men follow his lead and put their penis on a platter this summer. But is **the budgie-smuggler** look ever appropriate?

**Why budgie smuggler?**
The following is only speculation, I have no supporting evidence  that the expression derives from the illegal trade of songbirds.

A smuggler is someone who illegally transports goods, the smuggled  products are then sold on the black market. A *budgie* is short for [**budgerigar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budgerigar); a small, yellow and green bird that is usually kept as a pet. Back in the 19th century, the songbird trade was a highly profitable one, and bird catchers would invent the most cunning devices in order to capture these sought after birds.

Daniel Craig, making Britain proud again, in the James Bond movie that made him an international superstar.

[image]

Photo courtesy of *[The Mail Online](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1177819/I-borrowed-007s-budgie-smugglers---Man-arrested-airport-12-rare-songbirds-strapped-socks.html)*